# how to find elements of my custom array list that are not present in another array list

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<ParkingList> Parkings = new ArrayList<ParkingList>();
ArrayList<ParkingList> ParkingsDB = new ArrayList<ParkingList>();
```

for example, `Parkings` may contain (a,b,c,d) objects and `ParkingsDB` may contain (a,b)

how can i find c,d

i tried using this method but it didint work,

```
ArrayList<ParkingList> temp = new ArrayList<ParkingList>(Parkings);
temp.removeAll(ParkingsDB);
```

my class definition:

```
public class ParkingList {
     Rectangle R;
     String Name;
     int level;
     String BuildingName;

     public ParkingList(String BuildingName,String Name, Rectangle R, int level) {
         this.R=R;
         this.Name=Name;
         this.level=level;
         this.BuildingName=BuildingName;
     }
}
```

i just wanna know, was my method that i used above a correct method? maybe i have another problem i need to fix.

my criteria is , two objects are equal only if all of the attributes in one object are the same in another object.

Comment: Define "didn't work".  How is `ParkingList` defined?

Comment: by what criteria are two objects equal?

Comment: for example, Parkings contain these two objects
object 1: (mall,c1,rectangle1,1)
object 2: (school, b1, rectangle2,2)

ParkingsDB contains only this one object:
object 1: (mall,c1,rectangle1,1)

i want to find the objects that are in Parkings but are not in ParkingsDB , any object with even 1 element that has different value is not equal.

Comment: There are dozens, probably _hundreds_, of questions on SO asking how to find subsets, supersets, set differences, etc. on primitive arrays and various types of collections. The first thing for you to realize is that the fact you are using an `ArrayList` instead of some other kind of list, or any other kind of Collection, is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

in order to utilise `removeAll` on a collection of custom types you'll need to provide an implementation of the `equals` method and if possible also the `hashCode` method as it is used by certain collections in the collection API.

another solution would be to utilise `removeIf` and specify the criteria which defines when two or more objects are equal.

e.g.

```
ArrayList<ParkingList> temp = new ArrayList(Parkings);
temp.removeIf(x -> ParkingsDB.stream()
                                 .anyMatch(e -> e.getName().equals(x.getName())));
```

in this case, the criteria is when any given object in `temp` has the same name as any given object in `ParkingsDB` then it shall be removed from the `temp` list.

now you'll simply need to decide whether to provide your own implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` or utilise the example above; in all cases, you'll need to provide a *criteria which defines when two given objects are equal*.

---

This is irrelevant to the problem at hand, but you don't seem to respect the Java naming conventions at all.

variables as well as methods (except constructors which is a *special* type of a method) should start with a lowercase letter and follow the camelCase naming convention i.e rather than *Parkings* it should be *parkings*, rather than *Name* it should be *name* etc.

Also, you seem to have *freely* exposed the state of `ParkingList`. you *should* enforce *encapsulation* here by making all the variables *private* and only provide getters and setters where necessary.

Comment: this is when all of the attributes of object 1 is equal to object 2 in the other array list? or is this only when we find 1 equal attribute?

Comment: @Aominè. To be fully correct the OP did not say that mutating `Parkings` is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you, as it was already mentioned - to implement ParkingList.equals() method. For example you can generate it by IDE.

Than your code:

```
temp.removeAll(ParkingsDB);
```

will work as you expected. This happens since list implementation basically depends on equals() method for checking elements.

You may also use streams:

```
ArrayList<ParkingList> temp = Parkings.stream()
    .filter(parking -> !ParkingsDB.contains(parking))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```